# Interactively select multiple items

Tags: emacs, elisp

How can I let the user select multiple items from a list instead of just one? Like in the C-x b menu in helm.

Currently I can only select a single item instead of getting a complete list:

```
(defun test-main ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((choice (completing-read "Select: " '("item1 item2 item3"))))
    (message choice)))
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do that with `completing-read-multiple`:

```
(defun test-main ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((choice (completing-read-multiple "Select: " '("item1" "item2" "item3"))))
    (message "%S" choice)))
```

It returns the selected items as a list, so if you type `item2,item3` at the prompt, it returns `("item2" "item3")`.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't open a 'select-buffer' like completing-read.

Comment: I want the user to select options with C-SPC

Comment: It does show a 'select-buffer' after you hit TAB (you could add this information in the prompt)

Answer (score 2):

Because that's what vanilla `completing-read` does.  It reads and returns a *single* choice, providing completion to help you choose.

You can do what you are asking for with [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles).  It redefines function `completing-read` when `Icicle` mode is on.

Many Icicles commands are [multi-commands](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Commands), which means that you can make multiple input choices in a single command execution: a *multiple-choice* command.  You can [define your own](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Defining_Icicles_Commands)  multi-commands, using any actions.

And for any completion (not just for a multi-command), you can manipulate, save, and restore [sets of completion candidates](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Candidate_Sets).

(You can also enter [multiple inputs](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Inputs) in the minibuffer.  This is useful even for commands that read input *without* completion.)